# Circular Doubly Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

The removeNode() function implements a circular doubly linked list which has a sentinel node. What I am trying to do is defined in pseudo code next to the function. I simply just am having a hard time understanding how to do so.

```
#include "CDLList.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

ListNode *createList()
{
    ListNode *sentinel = new ListNode();
    sentinel->last = sentinel;
    sentinel->next = sentinel;

    return sentinel;
}

void destroyList(ListNode *&sentinel)
{
    // Delete any item nodes
    clearList(sentinel);

    // Delete the sentinel node
    delete sentinel;
    sentinel = nullptr;
}

bool isEmpty(ListNode *sentinel)
{
    return (sentinel == sentinel->next);
}

ListNode *findNode(ListNode *sentinel, string value)
{
    ListNode *pCurrNode = sentinel->next;
    while (pCurrNode != sentinel)
    {
        // Check if we found the node
        if (pCurrNode->item == value)
        {
            return pCurrNode;
        }

        // Move to next node
        pCurrNode = pCurrNode->next;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

void addItem(ListNode *sentinel, string value)
{
    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->item = value;
    newNode->last = sentinel->last;
    newNode->next = sentinel;

    sentinel->last->next = newNode;
    sentinel->last = newNode;
}

void removeNode(ListNode *node) // Implement this function!
{
    // Unlink node

    // Delete node
}
```

The removeNode() function is called within these two functions

```
void removeItem(ListNode *sentinel, string value)
{
    ListNode *node = findNode(sentinel, value);

    // If the item was not found, there's nothing to do (remove)
    if (node == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    removeNode(node);
}
void clearList(ListNode *sentinel)
{
    while (!isEmpty(sentinel))
    {
        removeNode(sentinel->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to do it on paper first... Draw a few lists on paper, and then see how you could do to remove the different nodes in those lists. When you think you have it figured out on paper, then try to translate that solution into code. The lists I recommend you "test" with includes an empty list, a list with a single node, a list where you remove the first node, the last node, or an interior node.

Comment: Still running into a blank with the actual implementation of this. Any additional suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function implementation:

```
void removeNode(ListNode *node)
{
    if(!isEmpty(node))
    {
        ListNode* nodeLast = node->last;
        ListNode* nodeNext = node->next;

        // Unlink node
        nodeLast->next = nodeNext;
        nodeNext->last = nodeLast;
    }

    // Delete node
    delete node;
}
```